# Not able to see foreign keys in PHPMyAdmin created using Laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to create a simple table with a foreign key referencing the default "users" table of Laravel.

Migration ran successfully, but when I see the newly created table in PHPMyAdmin, it doesn't show the foreign key.

Here is my simple migration file:

```
Schema::create('larachat_chat_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this and run `php artisan migrate`

```
Schema::create('larachat_chat_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('creator_id');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

and let me know if it works fine for you. what I think about this is, you need to create the column first, then you can specify it to be foreignkey. Refer [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Was about to post it, but you've already done so :)

Answer (score 1):

From phpmyadmin go to the specific table => Operations tab => Table options => change Storage Engine to innoDB save and return to your table you will see the relation view

Answer (score 0):

I noticed Eloquent seams not to build constraint whenever you create the field and set foreign at the same sentence. Like bellow:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('creator_id')
    ->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')
        ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

instead, you should do like

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('creator_id');

$table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

I am not a database specialist but I use dbeaver and mysql workbench and both deal differently whenever I apply those changes to migration scripts for they build and show relations in diagram only when I code like the second sample.

Can anyone confirm this, or even elaborate why? Please :) ! Thanks.

PS: Laravel 9.3.1

Comment: tip: To help you solve fixing relations try to use "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;" (mysql cli command). It would describe errors somewhere in the output if you run it right after the migration error.